# Simple Dotnetnuke or Django Q&A engine

Tags: web-development, .net-framework, django

Please recommend me some simple engine based on Dotnetnuke or Django that allows users to ask questions and the others to answer them. It doesn't need to be complex, but with tags and categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [**OSQA**](http://github.com/OSQA/osqa/), which uses Django and is a nice SO clone.

Look at [this thread on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) for other alternatives.